# Can I have a trigger that uses different tables argumments?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, database-trigger

I'm making a simple application with **MySql** and **I need to use a trigger**.
The trigger that I thought would update the vehicle table everytime a person is updated with a specific civil state.

I'm not sure about the trigger syntax, but I didn't find anything that explains the use of multiple argumments from differents tables.

Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_widow AFTER UPDATE
ON person
FOR EACH ROW
SET v.id_person = p.id_spouse 
FROM person p 
JOIN person p2 ON p.id_spouse = p2.id_person 
JOIN vehicle v ON v.id_person = p.id_person 
WHERE p2.civil_state = 5
```

It's returning **"Unknown system variable "id_person""** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `UPDATE` statement (not `SET` clause) to update values in table(s). I have changed the Trigger below (fixing all syntax errors). But logically, you still need to define exactly what you are trying to achieve.

In Triggers, we can access `NEW` and `OLD` value to achieve our logic.

```
DELIMITER $$  -- Define the Delimiter to something else other than ;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_widow AFTER UPDATE
ON person
FOR EACH ROW

  BEGIN  -- Trigger statement body starts with BEGIN clause

    UPDATE vehicle v 
    JOIN person p ON v.id_person = p.id_person 
    JOIN pessoa p2 ON p.id_spouse = p2.id_person 
    SET v.id_person = p.id_spouse 
    WHERE p2.civil_state = 5;

  END $$  -- END the Trigger statement
DELIMITER ;  -- redefine the Delimiter to ;
```

Comment: Just added a ; after the where clause and it worked well. Thank you!

Comment: @marianod323 Triggers are generally meaningless, if we dont use `NEW` and `OLD` keywords. Please refer this tutorial: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-triggers.aspx